# How to get Outlook to work with Snagit

Tags: snagit

I'm new to Snagit, and trying to figure out if it's possible to have integration with Outlook.

I did some research and it looks like they had an add-in in 2007, but the new MS add-in store it does not seem to have it available.

Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: I have Snagit and Outlook.  Ctrl-Al-P opens Snagit and copy (capture) what you want from Outlook

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it too well. I was thinking the other way around, where you could press a button in Outlook, and Snagit would pop-up, and any capture would automatically paste at the cursor in Outlook.

Comment: There is no button in Outlook (or any other regular App) that will launch SnagIT.  If configure for Ctrl-Alt-P then that will launch Snagit in Outlook (tested) or any other app. So the integration is just using the HotKey to launch SnagIT.  This works.

Answer (score 0):

Snagit (newest versions, Paid, from Techsmith) work with any and all applications.

Best to have Snagit set with Ctrl Alt P to capture an image and you can capture directly from Outlook. This works and I have tested it.

Snagit has changed since 2007 (greatly) and so also has Outlook.

See below.

[image: Outlook Integration with Snagit]

.

So there is no direct integration (none that I know of) other than to capture what you need, which is the function of SnagIt